what does mean + + operator in python numpy
I've met following statement in python numpy library
Z = inputs @ self.weights[1:].T + + self.weights[0]
I don't understand exactly what does it mean in this line of code
I've made researchtations and did not found proper explanation

Can you link to the line in the numpy library on github? It might be a typo.

a + + b is the same as a + (+ b).

There is no + + operator in Python. This is two separate operators, the unary positive operator and the binary sum operator. Observe:
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("x + + y")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              6 CALL_INTRINSIC_1         5 (INTRINSIC_UNARY_POSITIVE)
              8 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             12 RETURN_VALUE

Similar to the unary negative operator, -. e.g:
x = 10
y = -x
print(y) # -10

I suspect this is just a typo. Cases where unary + actually matters are extremely rare, and this doesn't look like one of them. Particularly, unary + is not an absolute value operator - if the input is negative, the output will be negative too.
